# Simple two-column LaTeX template

Tags: header-footer, two-column

I have been looking for a simple two-column LaTeX template.

I have attached a template that I like, but I am unable to remove the footer on the bottom of the page. Also, I would like to remove the Categories and Subject section as well.

I tried commenting the sections out using `%` in the `.tex` file, but that did not work. I also tried removing this in the `.cls` file but I received multiple errors when compiling.

Any suggestions or help?

http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/acm-tog-v1-2.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add this to the preamble of the example file, I think you get rid of all the stuff you want.  (But I haven't tried loading any external packages on top of the basic file.)

```
\typewidth6.5in 
\textwidth6.5in 
\oddsidemargin1in 
\evensidemargin1in
\makeatletter

\def\@maketitle{\newpage \thispagestyle{titlepage}\par
\centering \begingroup  \lineskip = \z@\null \vskip -7pt\relax %-24.5pt
\parindent\z@ \LARGE { \raggedright \hyphenpenalty\@M
{\titlefont \centering \@title\par}%
}
\label{@firstpg}
{ \vskip 13.5pt\relax \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \sf %vskip 13.5pt between title and author
 \begingroup \addtolength{\baselineskip}{2pt}
 \@author\par \vskip -2pt 
 \endgroup }
 \vskip 23pt\relax
 \endgroup
 }
\renewenvironment{abstract}
           {\par\footnotesize\noindent\ignorespaces}
           {\par\vskip5pt%
        \def\and{\unskip\/{\rm ; }}
 {\ifx\@acmformat\empty\else\vskip5pt\@acmformat\par\fi}\vskip24pt}

\def\category\relax
\def\@category\relax
\def\@categories\relax
\def\terms\relax
\def\@terms\relax
\def\keywords\relax
\def\@keywords\relax

\makeatother
```

You should also comment out these lines (if you are using the `TOG-Sample.tex` file to test):

```
% \category{I.3.7}{Computer Graphics}{Three-Dimensional Graphics and Realism}[Animation]
% \category{I.3.5}{Computer Graphics}{Computational Geometry and Object Modeling}[Physically based modeling]

% \terms{Experimentation, Human Factors}

% \keywords{Face animation, image-based modelling, iris animation, photorealism, physiologically-based modelling}

% \acmformat{Pamplona, V. F., Oliveira, M. M., and Baranoski, G. V. G. 2009. Photorealistic models for pupil light reflex and iridal pattern deformation.  {ACM Trans. Graph.} 28, 4, Article 106 (August 2009), 11 pages.\newline  DOI $=$  10.1145/1559755.1559763\newline http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1559755.1559763}
```

You can get rid of the commented sections once you are sure you don't need them.
(If you put the modifications into your own `.sty` file, say `acmtog-mods.sty` and then load it with `\usepackage`, you can get rid of the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` pair.)

In the end, it is probably better to avoid using so specific a class if you want want a 'simple' two-column layout.  The package `multicol`, and maybe a customizable class like `memoir` or one of the `KOMA-Script` ones is probably a better route.

Comment: Hi I tried adding this right after the \documentclass{} call but it does not remove the bottom footer. Do you know if I am missing something? Thanks

Comment: Also, how can I make all the margins 1 inch?

Comment: Jon
Ok thanks I got it to work now. So the changing of the margins can't be done with this class file?

Comment: Jon, I tried using \usepackage[margin= 1 in]{geometry}
This just distorted my page though.
Also, i have been trying to center the title and the author, by using \begin{center} and \end{center} and this does not seem to work. Sorry for all of the questions. Thanks for your help

Comment: Jon, I have tried \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
 \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
 \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

 \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
 \addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
But this distorts the page as well.

Comment: Jon, I found the following code that changes the margins all around to 1cm. But how can I change this code to make it 2.54cm = 1 in?
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm}

Also, the yes, the title should be centered and also, the author names too. 
Thanks

Comment: Jon, Yes when I add your margins code in and use the showframe, all the text fits into the box. But is this indicating that all the margins are 1inch?  Thanks

Comment: Jon, No the margins are way off. I'm not understanding how LaTeX is setting the margins. I measure them with a ruler from one edge of the page to the text and they are way off.

Comment: Jon, thanks so much for your help. I just have two last questions, and I will try to figure out the margins later myself.

1) How can I change/find out what the fontsize is?

2) And how can I center the Title and Authors?

Thanks

Comment: Jon,

Sweet!!! Thanks so much!! I'm a grad student writing my Qualifying Exam and this has helped me immensely. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @JPaul -- I'm glad it worked in the end!

Answer (score 2):

To fix that you would actually have to modify the class file.  I would recommend you look at the package multicol, read the documentation and then just start with the article class and create your own template.  Example below.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}\Large\textbf{Title for the document}\end{center}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{one}   \lipsum[1] 
    \section{two}   \lipsum[3]
    \section{three} \lipsum[5]
    \section{four}  \lipsum[7]
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `blindtext` or `lipsum` package?

Comment: My Miktex installation refused to install automatically or manually, so I provided an answer and now I am exterminating a Windows gremlin :(    I will edit it when my install works.